# What would be the next vertex when the edges have the same weights in dijkstra algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra

```
   2    3
A____B______C
|           |
|3          |5
|           |
D___________E
       5
```

When graph is like above, I want to find the shortest path from A to E

First I started with A and updated the distance of (B and D) as (2 and 3).
Then, the minimum distance of edge is 2 so I moved to B.

My question is which is the next Vertex since the distance of A-D is same as B-D...

Comment: Next vertex is D. As distance AD is 3. Distance AC is 2+3 = 5.

Comment: Do I have to choose unvisited && minimum distance vertex instead of minimum weighted edge?

Comment: See all steps posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are all steps to calculate distance AE. You may initialize each distance to `Infinity`, and start with `distance AA = 0`. At each step pick the candidate with minimum distance from A. And update its neighbors distance from A if the neighbor has not already been visited. Repeat the process until E is visited.

*Start at A (dist = 0).*

```
 1. Distance to B (through A) = 0 + 2 = 2.
 2. Distance to D (through A) = 0 + 3 = 3.
```

`sortedCandidates = [B=2, D=3]`
*Choose B (dist = 2).*

```
 1. Distance to C (through B) = 2 + 3 = 5.
```

`sortedCandidates = [D=3, C=5]`
*Choose D (dist = 3).*

```
 1. Distance to E (through D) = 3 + 5 = 8.
```

`sortedCandidates = [C=5, E=8]`
*Choose C (dist = 5).*

```
 1. Distance to E (through C) = 5 + 5 = 10 (reject as it is more than 8).
```

`sortedCandidates = [E=8]`
*Choose E (dist = 8).*

```
 1. Do nothing.
```

Distance AE = 8